# What is the maximal weight submodule of $\text{Hom}_{\mathfrak{g}}(M,N)$?

Tags: reference-request, rt.representation-theory, lie-algebras, modules, tensor-products

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a finite-dimensional semisimple Lie algebra over an algebraically closed field $\mathbb{K}$ of characteristic $0$.  Fix a Cartan subalgebra $\mathfrak{h}$ of $\mathfrak{g}$.  For any (not necessarily finite-dimensional) $\mathfrak{g}$-module $X$, write $X^\text{wt}$ for the sum of all $\mathfrak{g}$-submodules of $X$ which is $\mathfrak{h}$-semisimple.  Therefore, $X^\text{wt}$ is the maximal $\mathfrak{h}$-semisimple $\mathfrak{g}$-submodule of $X$.  In fact,
$$X^{\text{wt}}=\bigoplus_{\lambda\in\mathfrak{h}^*}\,X_\lambda\,,$$ 
where $$X_\lambda:=\Big\{x\in X\,\Big|\,h\cdot x=\lambda(h)\,x\text{ for each }h\in\mathfrak{h}\Big\}$$
for every $\lambda\in\mathfrak{h}^*$.

Here are the clarification of some notations.  Let $M$ and $N$ be $\mathfrak{g}$-modules.   Then, $M^*$ is the usual algebraic dual $\text{Hom}_{\mathbb{K}}(M,\mathbb{K})$ of $M$, and we identify $M^*\underset{\mathbb{K}}{\otimes}N$ as a $\mathfrak{g}$-submodule of $\text{Hom}_{\mathbb{K}}(M,N)$ via the canonical injection given by the linear extension of the assigments $$(f\otimes n)\mapsto \big(m\mapsto f(m)\,n\big)$$ for all $f\in M^*$, $m\in M$, and $n\in N$.  For example, we have
$$\left(M^*\right)_\lambda=\left(M_{-\lambda}\right)^*$$
for every $\lambda\in\mathfrak{h}^*$, making
$$\left(M^*\right)^\text{wt}=\bigoplus_{\lambda\in\mathfrak{h}^*}\,\left(M_{-\lambda}\right)^*\,.$$

Suppose that $M$ and $N$ are $\mathfrak{h}$-weight $\mathfrak{g}$-modules.    I would like to know if there has been any study on the $\mathfrak{g}$-module $\big(\text{Hom}_{\mathbb{K}}(M,N)\big)^{\text{wt}}$.  If $L$ is also an $\mathfrak{h}$-weight $\mathfrak{g}$-module, then we have the following easy fact: $$\text{Hom}_{\mathfrak{g}}\left(L\underset{\mathbb{K}}{\otimes}M,N\right)\cong \text{Hom}_{\mathfrak{g}}\Big(L,\big(\text{Hom}_{\mathbb{K}}(M,N)\big)^{\text{wt}}\Big)\,.$$
If all the $\mathfrak{h}$-weight spaces of $M$ and $N$ are finite-dimensional, then can we at least expect something like $$\big(\text{Hom}_{\mathbb{K}}(M,N)\big)^{\text{wt}}=\left(M^*\underset{\mathbb{K}}{\otimes}N\right)^\text{wt}\,?$$
Do we know whether
$$\left(X\underset{\mathbb{K}}{\otimes} Y\right)^{\text{wt}}=(X^{\text{wt}})\underset{\mathbb{K}}{\otimes} (Y^{\text{wt}})$$
holds for all $\mathfrak{g}$-modules $X$ and $Y$?